# node-github: "getStatsContributors" doesn't return results properly

Tags: node.js, git, github, node-github

This is how I'm using the method:

```
github.repos.getStatsContributors({
         repo: 'Cloudformation-Webserver',
         owner : 'DorrinPk'
    }, function (err, res) { 
        console.log(err, res);
    });
```

The first time I run it for the repo I get null results. The second time I run it I get :

```
null { data: [ { total: 4, weeks: [Object], author: [Object] } ],   meta:    { 'x-ratelimit-limit': '5000',
     'x-ratelimit-remaining': '4968',
     'x-ratelimit-reset': '1499712495',
     'x-oauth-scopes': 'admin:org, admin:repo_hook, notifications, repo, user',
     'x-github-request-id': 'A05B:0684:271B6:59CB1:5963C4D0',
     'x-github-media-type': 'github.v3; format=json',
     etag: '"f1ea81d88281adf31e1178d0804f230c"',
     status: '200 OK' } }
```

I know `total:4` is the number of my commits on the repo but I only get `[Object]` back for `author` and `weeks`.

am I doing something wrong? I was expecting to get similar results to [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you are printing out to the console is the `err` object from the response. In this case the request was successful, so the error is null.

The second thing you are writing is the response object. When using the `console.log` method like that it will not display all levels deep of an object and you must either use the [inspector](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/) to get a better look or write out the property itself (in your case you could use `console.log(res.data[0].author)`)

You are getting the correct results, it is just that the `console.log` method is printing out differently than what you were expecting to see, but it is all there.

Comment: oh that's great. I should have looked in the api docs on what does `author` object contained. Thanks!